# Build fat jar in maven with dependencies only

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I `use maven-shade-plugin` in my java project.

I have a module called `core` and i would like to pack all its dependencies into one single jar. I don't wan't to create fat big jar every time and deploy it along with my application code. My application jar has size < 1 MB but dependencies > 20 MB

On my server i would run my application like:

`java -cp core.lib.jar:core.jar myApp`

I need to deploy only `core.jar` to my server when i change application code and need to upload `core.lib.jar` only when i change dependencies (this is very rare).

There's a lot of docs how to build fat jar with java sources but i want to exclude them and deliver it to the server independently.

There is two maven plugins for building fat jar: assembly and shade. I want to stick with shade.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>core</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When i run `mvn -pl core shade:shade` i get error: `core: Failed to create shaded artifact, project main artifact does not exist`

I thought that that option:

core

would exclude my sources from the artifact.

I set `phase` to `none` because i don't want to create fat jar when i want to run `package`.
I would like to run `mvn shade:shade` and have updated fat jar.

I'm not an expert in maven or its plugins, so any help is very appreciated :)

Comment: By using maven-assembly-plugin you can package a jar/zip with the dependencies only and another jar which contains your application code.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used shade plugin by myself so I can't provide any practical guidance, however it seems like you need a multi-module maven project:

1. Refactor your project (move the folders) to look like this:

```
my-project
  |__app
  |    |__src 
  |    |  |__main( (and all the production sources/resources inside)
  |    |  |__test (all the tests/test resources inside)
  |    |__pom.xml
  |__core-lib
  |    |__pom.xml
  |__  pom.xml
```

`my-project/pom.xml` could be a "multi-module" aggregator: it should have `<packaging>pom</packaging>` and have the following:

```
<modules>
  <module>app</module>
  <module>core-lib</module>
</modules>
```

Now `app` module could be a place where you write the code of your application. It will change often, but it won't produce any fat jar - only a regular jar with a compiled code from this module only (in your example, it will be 1mb artifact).

The `core-lib` module will be a module that in it's `pom.xml` will contain the definitions of the shade / assembly plugin and this module will be responsible for the creation of the "fat jar". In its `dependences` section it will list all the 3rd party dependencies/code that you'll have to change 'rarely' (in your case, the one with 20 mb artifact).

If you need that, the "app" module could depend on "core-lib" module so that the application will have an access to the classes from the library.

So your usual workflow will be:

```
cd my-project/app
mvn package
```

If you want to build both application and core-libraries, then:

```
cd my-project
mvn package
```

You can read about multi modules [here](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module) or [here](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

Comment: The layout for all kinds of projects in Maven is `src/main/java` for production code. `src/test/java` for test code ... follow the conventions. Your suggestion violates the convention over configuration paradigm which should be avoided.

Comment: @khmarbaise: Yes, sure, It was a typo - I've fixed the answer Thanks for pointing that. Having said that I would like to emphasize (mainly for Alexander who has asked that question)  that the main "point" of the answer was the recommendation to use multi-module feature of maven.

Comment: Thanks @MarkBramnik for suggestion! I already use maven multi-module feature. I have already modules like: core, app, server, etc. I would like to avoid creation of modules just for packaging purpose, and don't create app-lib, server-lib, core-lib.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to move this block under plugin / configuration

```
                <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>core</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </artifactSet>
```

Used to be in `executions` block.

Now i can run `mvn -pl core shade:shade` and have fat jar with dependencies only :)